# mongo 4.2.11 standalone bulkWrite gives transaction error

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I'm trying to execute a collection.bulkWrite() using the 4.2.11 mongo shell (NB: not mongosh) against a standalone mongo server.

I'm **not using any transactions** (as far as I know!).

This method has worked for me on other servers, but I'm now getting the error as shown below. I cannot find any reason why the mongo error is referring to transactions, or why this update is not working!

```
2023-04-12T22:29:44.296+0000 E  QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: WriteCommandError({
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "Transaction numbers are only allowed on a replica set member or mongos",
        "code" : 20,
        "codeName" : "IllegalOperation"
}) :
WriteCommandError({
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "Transaction numbers are only allowed on a replica set member or mongos",
        "code" : 20,
        "codeName" : "IllegalOperation"
})
WriteCommandError@src/mongo/shell/bulk_api.js:417:48
executeBatch@src/mongo/shell/bulk_api.js:915:23
Bulk/this.execute@src/mongo/shell/bulk_api.js:1163:21
DBCollection.prototype.bulkWrite@src/mongo/shell/crud_api.js:213:20
updateUploads@checkClientUploads.mongodb:195:7
@checkClientUploads.mongodb:233:26
forEachClient/<@checkClientUploads.mongodb:16:7
DBQuery.prototype.forEach@src/mongo/shell/query.js:494:9
forEachClient@checkClientUploads.mongodb:11:3
@checkClientUploads.mongodb:221:1
```

The bulkWrite statement is as follows:

```js
const results = db.getCollection(name).bulkWrite([
                {
                        "updateOne" : {
                                "filter" : {
                                        "_id" : ObjectId("6076c9a4dd8cf70036595f62")
                                },
                                "update" : {
                                        "$set" : {
                                                "status" : "saved"
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                },
                {
                        "updateOne" : {
                                "filter" : {
                                        "_id" : ObjectId("6076c9dedd8cf70036595f67")
                                },
                                "update" : {
                                        "$set" : {
                                                "status" : "saved"
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                },
                // several other similar records, all with unique _id in the filter
        ],
        { ordered: false }
)
```

Comment: Okay, it appears I can get these updates to work if I remove the `writeConcern=majority` argument from the connection string. I don't know why `majority` is not allowed  for the standalone instance I'm connecting to, but suspect it's possibly to do with some kind of automatic transaction. Manual has a slightly cryptic note about "majority write operations could possibly roll back in the event of a transient loss"

Comment: On a standalone MongoDB  the `writeConcern` is not relevant, I would assume.

Comment: It's not completely irrelevant:
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.2/reference/write-concern/#standalone

and in my case, this did solve the problem, but I can't see why (or else I'd post an answer here)